# Highstock Charts React: Generating chart with multiple series is displayed incorrectly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, highcharts

I'm trying to create a Component that wraps a Highstock chart.
It takes `charts` and `chartHeight` as props, and I'm generating the chart `options` like so:

```
setChartOptions({
        chart: {
            height: (props.charts.length) * props.chartHeight,
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Title'
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 0,
            buttons: [],
            inputEnabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            split: true
        },
        series: buildSeries(),
        yAxis: buildYAxis()
    })
```

I'm using the functions `buildSeries` and `buildYAxis`:

```
const buildSeries = () => {
    let series = [];

    props.charts.forEach((chart, index) => {
        series.push({
            type: chart.type,
            name: chart.title,
            data: chart.data,
            yAxis: index,
            color: chart.color
        })
    })

    return series;
}

const buildYAxis = () => {
    let yAxis = [];

    props.charts.forEach((chart, index) => {
        yAxis.push({
            labels: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -3
            },
            title: {
                text: chart.title,
            },
            height: props.chartHeight,
            top: index * props.chartHeight,
            lineWidth: 2,
            resize: {
                enabled: true
            },
            offset: 0
        })
    })

    return yAxis;
}
```

But the charts are displayed incorrectly:
[image]

As the picture shows, the first chart is displayed in the very bottom (Blue) and the large gap between the Title and the chart is supposed to hold the first chart.
When I enter the return values of `buildSeries` and `buildYAxis` the chart is displayed correctly.
I used the following link as an example of a functioning chart:
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/stock/candlestick-and-volume

Am I missing something with the initialization of the options? Or is this a bug within Highstock charts?

Thank you

Comment: Hi @user10000, Could you reproduce the problem in some online code editor? You can start from: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-yi81d?file=/demo.jsx

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek I managed getting it to work properly here: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-8odcl?file=/demo.jsx

But copying this exact same piece of code to my project still returns the same weird behavior.

Comment: There must be some difference. Maybe you are using some different Highcharts/wrapper version?